# Is there a SFSafariViewController equivalent for OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I want to display web content in 'reader' mode, when available, within my Mac app. iOS has [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller?changes=_2) to simply achieve this. I can't find anything straightforward in OSX.

Must I head down the root of using a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) and a reader service like [Mercury](https://mercury.postlight.com/web-parser/)?

Ta.

Comment: Mercury has been taken down now, so I don't know what the options are...